# Find: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}}{\sin x^6}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I even approach such a question? Obviously l'Hospital rule would be a mess and I don't know how to even start. Most of the limits we deal with are way simpler than this.

Comment: Do you know  Taylor series?

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that be extremely complicated?

Comment: Why would L'Hospital be a mess? It's all a bunch of very simple functions...

Comment: The substitution $y=x^2$ would arguably make it a bit less threatening. L'Hopital's rule does actually work fairly neatly here, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'Hopital:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{-2x+2x^3+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}}{6x^5\cos(x^6)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2x^5}{x^2+1}}{6x^5\cos(x^6)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^5}{(x^2+1)(6x^5\cos(x^6))}\\=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\overbrace{\sec(x^6)}^{\to 1}}{3\underbrace{(x^2+1)}_{\to 1}}=\frac 1 3$$

Comment: Is it correct to say that:
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x^5}{6x^5\cos {(x^6)}} = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2x^5}{6x^5} = \frac{1}{3}$$
?

Comment: What's the reason for introducing the secant?

Comment: theres no need to say that... simplify the $2x^5$ and the $6x^5$ and you will get $\frac{1}{3cos(x^6)}$ and when the limit of x tends to 0 on that it will become $\frac13$

Comment: @Agami You can't ignore $\cos(x^6)$ but you **can** say that:

$$\require{cancel}\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{2\cancel{x^5}}{6\cancel{x^5}\cos {(x^6)}} =  \frac{1}{3}$$ and $\cos(x^6)\to 1$ when $x\to 0$

Comment: OK thanks.
Just to clarify: I wasn't ignoring $\cos{(x^6)}$, but I noticed that as x approaches 0 $cos x = 1$ so multiplying by 1 doesn't change it.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [Series expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html), $$\ln(1+z)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-z)^r}r$$

and $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin h}h=1$

Comment: I don't know what this means.

Comment: @Agami, Please pinpoint your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
$$\ln(1+x^2) = x^2 - \frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^6}{3} + \mathcal{O}(x^7)$$
and
$$\sin x^6 = x^6 + \mathcal{O}(x^7)$$

Comment: OK let me elaborate a bit:
I'm doing the first course in calculus so the questions are usually at a more basic level. I assume there is a trick hiding here that makes this solvable without using advanced techniques.
I've tried the following:
$$\frac{(\ln{(1+x)}-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2})\frac{1}{x^6}}{\sin^6 x * \frac{1}{x^6}}$$
So this simplifies the bottom to $1$ but I don't know how to go from here. I'm left with: 
$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^6}-\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{2x^2}$$

Comment: What do you call as an advanced technique? For example in my mind it is easier to use Taylor series than to approach it as @Nehorai did.

Answer (score 2):

Set $y=x^2$ and ignore the sine (thanks to the limit of the ratio $\sin(t)/t$).

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}}{\sin(x^6)}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(1+y)-y+\frac{y^2}{2}}{\sin(y^3)}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(1+y)-y+\frac{y^2}{2}}{y^3}.$$

If you know the Taylor's development of $\ln(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}2+\frac{y^3}3-\frac{y^4}4\cdots$, you recognize the first two terms which are compensated, and the answer is the coefficient of the cubic one,

$$\frac13.$$

Otherwise, L'Hospital comes to the rescue,

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\frac1{1+y}-1+y}{3y^2}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y^2}{3y^2(1+y)}.$$

No mess.